# Saving data from a programmatically added vba text box

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I am trying to create a function which programmatically adds text boxes to a blank userform depending on the users desired number of textboxes.

Currently I have a function which does this, however I cannot save the values of the text boxes. I have tried referencing the textboxes several ways however none of them seem to work (despite the same methods working before in a separate code, although the textboxes in question were not programmatically added)

```
Function addtxtbox(number_of_textboxes As Integer)

Dim option_names As New UserForm2
Dim names As String
Dim test As String   
Dim textbox  As Object
Dim submit As Object

For i = 1 To number_of_textboxes
    Set textbox = option_names.Controls.Add("Forms.textbox.1")
    With textbox
        .Left = 30
        .Width = 200
        .Top = 20 * i
        .Left = 20
    End With

    MsgBox (textbox.Name)'used to find the name of the textboxes

Next

option_names.Show

names = "TextBox1" 'correct name of the 1st textbox according to the msgbox above.
MsgBox (names) 'msgbox is always blank
test = option_names.names 'Compile error: Method or data members not found
'test = textbox.TextBox1.Value 'run time error 418 object does not support this property or method
MsgBox (test) 

End Function
```

Comment: What is the code in your `UserForm2`?  (I created a UserForm1 with a form `Click` event that called `addtxtbox 4`, and a blank UserForm2 with a form `Click` event that simply did a `Me.Unload`.  When I ran it, and clicked the first form, it correctly added 4 textboxes, displayed the 2nd form, allowed me to type something into the first text box, then after clicking the form the code returned to the `addtxtbox` function where `"TextBox1"` message was displayed and, by using `test = option_names.Controls(names)`, the value entered into the textbox was then displayed.)

Comment: My code for userform2 is simply a blank userform with a command button. The command button has the code  
'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub'
Apart from that there is no code

Comment: @YowE3K I took your advice and used    <test = option_names.Controls(names)>    and the code text box data was displayed. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I still can't work out why `names = "TextBox1"` followed by `MsgBox (names)` returned blank - those two lines are simply an assignment to a string variable and then immediately displaying that string variable - so that is **really** weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to name your textboxes with a predictable sequence:

```
For i = 1 To number_of_textboxes

    Set textbox = option_names.Controls.Add("Forms.textbox.1")
    With textbox
        .Left = 30
        .Width = 200
        .Top = 20 * i
        .Left = 20
        .Name = "dynamic_" & i  '<<<<<<< name the textbox
    End With

    MsgBox (textbox.Name)'used to find the name of the textboxes

Next
```

Now you can use something like:

```
For i = 1 To number_of_textboxes

    MsgBox "Textbox# " & i & " has value '" & _
            Me.Controls("dynamic_" & i).Text & "'"

Next
```

Comment: Thank you!! The Me.Controls was what was needed, naming the text boxes was a useful idea too, I very much appreciate the help!